# Loop through a list?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id ="questions">
    <li class="question"></li>
    <li class="question"></li>
    <li class="question"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I iterate through each list element?

So far I have:

```
$("#questions li").each(function() { });
```

But no luck, any ideas?

I for got to mention that all but the first li is being added on the fly, is this why the loop is not picking them up?

Comment: Looks  like you're doing fine. You've just got to do whatever is necessary in the function. After all, you iterate in order to do something, not just for the sake of it.

Comment: I put an alert('a'); in the loop and it only fires once, should fire 3 times for each question

Comment: @beans Show your *actual code*, describe your *expected output*, and your *actual* output. Don't make people guess, it helps nobody.

Comment: Doesn't make sense - zero alerts is feasible; three alerts is feasible; one alert!?!?! You have just one element with `id="questions"` on the page don't you?

Comment: I've found out the issue, the page just starts with one li, then more are added by the user

Comment: That might have something to do with it!

Comment: So at *what point* do you expect this to iterate through the list? On page-load? Each time the user 'adds' another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do as you iterate through each list item? Using the `.each` function should work great. If you're having a problem with it though it might be because you are calling the function too early, in which case the `ready function` (as @roXon mentioned) will fix that. Otherwise, if you're having issues. It might be because of the space you have between the `id` and `=` sign on your `<ul>`

Here's a jQuery example of iterating through each element:

```
$('#questions li').each(function() {
    var i = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(this).text("List item " + i);
});
```

Feel free to play around with it: http://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/gkayG

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ujiver/1/edit)**</kbd>

Use `.ready function`, doing so the DOM modifications will take place once it's read.

```
$(function(){
   $("#questions li").each(function() {
          // DO SOMETHING
   });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Or use your fireBug or devTool to get any other possible errors.

Comment: @beans than you have not included properly the jQuery library. It should work.

Comment: @beans look at the "LIVE DEMO" link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function parameters to get the index and value of each list item:

```
$("#questions li").each(function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + '' + $(value).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are iterating through each list item.

If you change the dom elements to:

```
<ul id ="questions">
    <li class="question">one</li>
    <li class="question">two</li>
    <li class="question">three</li> 
</ul>
```

and then use the following jQuery code when the document loads:

```
$(function(){
   $("#questions li").each(function() {
          alert($(this).html()); //Or whatever you want to do with that item
   });
});
```

You should be outputting:

- one
- two
- three

Note: you can test your JavaScript and jQuery at http://jsfiddle.net/